# when using the sumif function how do you get the [sum_range] to only add the positive numbers?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

when using the sumif function how do you get the [sum_range] to only add the positive numbers?

so if the function is  =sumif(A:H,C34,H:H) how do I only add the positive numbers in column H

Answer (score 1):

In your posted formula `=sumif(A:H,C34,H:H)` because the test range is A:H , the range that is summed is actually H:O (the shape of A:H = 8 columns starting at top left cellof H:H)  Not sure if this is what you intended.  Given the overlap in the criterai and sum ranges I suspect not.  BTW this means cell J34 will always be included in the sum

SUMIFS is only available in Exel 2007 and later and would work for  =SUMIFS(H:H, A:A, C34, H:H, ">0")

Unlike the range and criteria arguments in the SUMIF function, in the SUMIFS function, each criteria_range argument must contain the same number of rows and columns as the sum_range argument.

If you are using Excel 2003 or earlier, or if the range behviour described above is required, you can use somthing like,

```
=SUM(H:H*(A:A=$C$34)*(H:H>0))
```

or

```
=SUM(H:O*(A:H=$C$34)*(H:O>0))   ' this one won't work as is, you will have to resolve the overlapping ranges
```

entered as an array formula (Ctrl-Shift-Enter)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SUMIFS function:

```
=SUMIFS(H:H, A:H, C34, H:H, ">0")
```

The `sum_range` is at the beginning in this case, instead of the end in this case